# Create a Single column using values fom multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create a new column in a Pandas data frame based on values from three columns,if the value for each column ['A','B','C'] is greater than 5 then output = 1 and output =0 if there is any value in either one of the columns ['A','B','C'] that is less then 5
The data frame looks like this:

```
A   B   C
5   8   6
9   2   1
6   0   0
2   2   6
0   1   2
5   8   10  
5   5   1
9   5   6
```

Expected output:

```
A   B   C    new_column
5   8   6    1
9   2   1    0
6   0   0    0   
2   2   6    0
0   1   2    0
5   8   10   1
5   5   1    0
9   5   6    1
```

I tried using this code,but it is not giving me the desired output:

```
conditions = [(df['A'] >= 5) , (df['B'] >= 5) , (df['C'] >= 5)]
choices = [1,1,1]
df['new_colum'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0)
```

Comment: Try `df['new_column'] = (df['A'] >= 5) & (df['B'] >= 5) & (df['C'] >= 5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need chain conditions by `&` for `bitwise AND`:

```
conditions = (df['A'] >= 5) & (df['B'] >= 5) & (df['C'] >= 5)
```

Or use [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check if all values in row are `True`s:

```
conditions = (df[['A','B','C']] >= 5 ).all(axis=1)
#if need all columns >=5
conditions = (df >= 5 ).all(axis=1)
```

And then convert mask to integer for `True, False` to `1, 0`:

```
df['new_colum'] = conditions.astype(int)
```

Or use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['new_colum'] = np.where(conditions, 1, 0)

print (df)
   A  B   C  new_colum
0  5  8   6          1
1  9  2   1          0
2  6  0   0          0
3  2  2   6          0
4  0  1   2          0
5  5  8  10          1
6  5  5   1          0
7  9  5   6          1
```